# Ray hit testing with Model3D

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

I need to test ray-model intersections. I know that there is a build in method to test a ray intersection with Viewport3D ( https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf3d/2009/05/18/3d-hit-testing/ )

I can't find any way to use it to test a Model3D. I need to test whole model for intersection, not only a visible part.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I think I have found a solution. What I can do is:

```
ModelVisual3D testModel = new ModelVisual3D();
testModel.Content = model;     //model is Model3DGroup
...
RayHitTester(testModel, origin, direction);
```

And it works as supposed!